# How to add a textbox to a website to accept and process large chunks of user data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a simple one-page website with two text boxes. One accepts a multiple columns of data that a user pastes from Google Sheets into the text box. I've written code to process the data and output it (to the second text box).

The text box needs to be able to accept three rows and an unlimited number of columns.

I'm struggling to figure out how to insert this text box into the website and extract all the data from it at once. The first step in the code (which works without issue) is to make a list from each row.

Sample input is as follows:

```
Row 1: A \t B
Row 2: 1 \t 2
Row 3: ! \t ?
```

Note: Data pasted into Notepad from Google sheets is separated by a tab, so I have assumed it will be the same in the text box.

I need to use this data to make three lists:

```
1 = ['A', 'B']
2 = ['1', '2']
3 = ['!', '?']
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this or where to look for guidance on this? I've Googled as many combinations of this question as I could but I have not yet found anything pertaining to processing user input from copying and pasting multiple rows and columns from Google Sheets into a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Split on newlines `\n`, then split on whitespace `\s`:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
var rows = text.split("\n");
var data = rows.map(row => row.split(/\s/g));
console.log(data);
```

```html
<textarea id="text" rows="20" cols="80">A B
1 2
! ?</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you! I realised I phrased my question poorly. A better summary would be:
"How do I insert a textbox that functions like Notepad into a webpage?"